# Apache POI pptx to image take too much time for processing

Tags: java, swing, apache-poi, executable-jar

I have code to convert pptx slide into image and display the image in swing panel.

When i run my code in eclipse, it takes 10 Sec to display the panel whereas same code run via jar, it takes more than one minute to open the panel.

It happens only when user open it first time, Later it loads faster.

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Here i included the code

```
 // currentPage - Slide number to display
 // source - pptx file path
 public void Display(int currentPage, String source) {
    try {

        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(source);
        XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(is);
        is.close();

        double zoom = 1; // magnify it by 2
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.setToScale(zoom, zoom);

        Dimension pgsize = ppt.getPageSize();

        XSLFSlide[] slides = ppt.getSlides();
        all = slides.length;
        lblPage.setText(currentPage + " / " + all);

        current = currentPage;

        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(pgsize.width, pgsize.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        Graphics2D graphics = img.createGraphics();
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
        graphics.transform(at);

        graphics.setColor(Color.white);
        graphics.clearRect(0, 0, pgsize.width, pgsize.height);
        graphics.fill(new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, pgsize.width, pgsize.height));

        System.out.println("Before draw: " + new Date());

        slides[currentPage - 1].draw(graphics);

        System.out.println("After draw: " + new Date());

        // save the output
        Image newImg = img.getScaledInstance(lblPresentasi.getWidth(), lblPresentasi.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(newImg);
        lblPresentasi.setIcon(icon);
        lblPresentasi.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getComponent();
                Dimension size = label.getSize();
                Image resized = icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(size.width-10, size.height-10, Image.SCALE_FAST);
                label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(resized));
            }
        });
        graphics.dispose();
        newImg.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}// end of method Display()
```

Comment: The first time the rendering takes place an XML definition for the preset shapes is loaded ... this usually takes 1-2 secs. But 1 min. of loading looks like there might be some schema loading in background - please try your example without network and see if it makes any difference. If not, you need to profile your applications. If you want, you can post your example (code & ppt/x) in POIs bugzilla and I'll have a look onto it.

Comment: @kiwiwings: When i execute in eclipse, it takes only 4 Sec whereas the problem is in JAR. I build my JAR with one-jar to refer lib jar.  Does it affect anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This delay was caused by One-Jar custom class loader. At first time, it takes more time to load the dependency libraries and load it classes.

So, I removed one-jar and using [JarSplice](http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice) to load the dependency libraries classes , it works great.